# PHP class: Global variable as property in class

Tags: php, class, variables, methods

I have a global variable outside my class = $MyNumber;

How do I declare this as a property in *myClass*?
For every method in my class, this is what I do:

```
class myClass() {

    private function foo() {
         $privateNumber = $GLOBALS['MyNumber'];
    }

}
```

I want this

```
class myClass() {

    //What goes here?
    var $classNumber = ???//the global $MyNumber;

    private function foo() {
         $privateNumber = $this->classNumber;
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** I want to create a variable based on the global $MyNumber but
 modified before using it in the methods

something like: var $classNumber = global $MyNumber + 100;

Comment: The more important question is: Why do you need that? There is probably a design mistake in here.

Comment: @elusie: I want refer to $MyNumber differently in my classes

Comment: Why do you need a global variable in the first place? They are not needed in most cases. What is that global variable for?

Comment: PHP Does not have pointers. It does have references, which sometimes work like pointers, but they are not. Do not try to emulate pointer functionality; you will just cause massive pain for future-you trying to debug it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You probably *don't* really want to be doing this, as it's going to be a nightmare to debug, but it seems to be possible.  The key is the part where you assign by *reference* in the constructor.

```
$GLOBALS = array(
    'MyNumber' => 1
);

class Foo {
    protected $glob;

    public function __construct() {
        global $GLOBALS;
        $this->glob =& $GLOBALS;
    }

    public function getGlob() {
        return $this->glob['MyNumber'];
    }
}

$f = new Foo;

echo $f->getGlob() . "\n";
$GLOBALS['MyNumber'] = 2;
echo $f->getGlob() . "\n";
```

The output will be

```
1
2
```

which indicates that it's being assigned by reference, not value.

As I said, it will be a nightmare to debug, so you really shouldn't do this.  Have a read through the wikipedia article on [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)); basically, your object should ideally manage its own data and the methods in which that data is modified; even public properties are generally, IMHO, a bad idea.

Comment: I think the code line "global $GLOBALS;" is useless. $GLOBALS are accessible in the global scope by default. And Warning :
As of PHP 8.1.0, write access to the entire $GLOBALS array is no longer supported

Answer (score 15):

Try to avoid globals, instead you can use something like this

```
class myClass() {
 private $myNumber;

 public function setNumber($number) {
  $this->myNumber = $number;
 }
}
```

Now you can call

```
$class = new myClass();
$class->setNumber('1234');
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply use the [global keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

e.g.:

```php
class myClass() {
    private function foo() {
        global $MyNumber;
        ...
```

$MyNumber will then become accessible (and indeed modifyable) within that method.

However, the use of globals is often frowned upon (they can give off a bad code smell), so you *might* want to consider using a singleton class to store anything of this nature. (Then again, without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve this might be a very bad idea - a [define](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) could well be more useful.)

Answer (score 4):

What I've experienced is that you can't assign your global variable to a class variable directly.

```
class myClass() {

    public $var = $GLOBALS['variable'];

    public function func() {
         var_dump($this->var);
    }
}
```

With the code right above, you get an error saying "***Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$GLOBALS'***"

But if we do something like this,

```
class myClass() {

    public $var = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->var = $GLOBALS['variable'];
    }

    public function func() {
         var_dump($this->var);
    }

}
```

Our code will work fine.

Where we assign a global variable to a class variable must be inside a function. And I've used constructor function for this.

So, you can access your global variable inside the every function of a class just using **$this->var**;

Answer (score 3):

What about using constructor?

```
class myClass {

   $myNumber = NULL;

   public function __construct() {
      global myNumber;

      $this->myNumber = &myNumber; 
   }

   public function foo() {
      echo $this->myNumber;
   }

}
```

Or much better this way (passing the global variable as parameter when inicializin the object - read only)

```
class myClass {

   $myNumber = NULL;

   public function __construct($myNumber) {
      $this->myNumber = $myNumber; 
   }

   public function foo() {
      echo $this->myNumber;
   }

}
$instance = new myClass($myNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a property from inside a class you should:

```
private $classNumber = 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that globals can be used as follows:

Create new class:

```
class globalObj{

    public function glob(){        
        global $MyNumber;  
        return $this;  
    }
}
```

So, now the global is an object and can be used in the same way:
`$this->glob();`

Answer (score -2):

```
class myClass 
{
protected $foo;

public function __construct(&$var)
{
    $this->foo = &$var;
}

public function foo()
{
    return ++$this->foo;
}
}
```

Comment: Please use proper formatting and don't post code only, elaborate on your answer.